# Angular 2 AOT not like moduleId in my components

Tags: angular, systemjs

How do I get around this?

As far as I know, JIT needs moduleId's on the components to find the template and styles if the component has one.

However, AOT doesnt use module and you get a "Cannot find name 'module'" error when compiling for AOT.

I don't want to go through all my modules and remove the Id for AOT, as I use JIt for DEV and AOT for production release only in order to get the performance benefits.

I've used the new angular 4 seed app for this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html