# Angular 4 AOT build not working with Lodash Library

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular2-aot, aot

Angular 4 AOT build not working with Lodash Library.

I managed to get lodash to build and serve in JIT.
But I'm having trouble with the build for AOT.

AOT works fine when I dont have lodash, but I want to get it to work with lodash.

**This is the command Im using:**

"build:aot": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js",

**Error I get in git bash:**

warning.indexOf is not a function

**Attempt at resolving the rollup error:**

I updated the **rollup-config.js** file to this:

if ( warning.message.indexOf("The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined'") > -1 ) { return;

**from this:**

if ( warning.indexOf("The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined'") > -1 ) { return;

**Outcome:**

This seemed to run the rollup fine, but then when I do a "**npm run serve:aot**" I get the follow console error with the build.js file:

**Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: void 0 is not a function.**

This could be something to do with the lodash lib being added maybe?

**This is my tsconfig:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../../node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/app/app.module.ts",
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true
  }
}
```

**This is my systemjs.config:**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'lodash':                    'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      lodash: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**This is my rollup-config:**

```
import rollup      from 'rollup'
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs    from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify      from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'
//paths are relative to the execution path
export default {
  entry: 'src/main.js',
  dest: 'aot/dist/build.js', // output a single application bundle
  sourceMap: true,
  sourceMapFile: 'aot/dist/build.js.map',
  format: 'iife',
  onwarn: function(warning) {
    // Skip certain warnings
    // should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
    if ( warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED' ) { return; }
    // intercepts in some rollup versions
    if ( warning.indexOf("The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined'") > -1 ) { return; }
    // console.warn everything else
    console.warn( warning.message );
  },
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
    commonjs({
      include: ['node_modules/rxjs/**']
    }),
    uglify()
  ]
}
```

**This is my index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart - aot</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

  <script src="build.js"></script>

</html>
```

**Note:**

I mention I use lodash in my map for the systemjs.config file. And in the package section of this file.

**I'm using the angular.io quickstart seed app for this build: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html**

Screen grab of git error for running **npm run build:aot** with lodash set to "'lodash':'npm:lodash/lodash/core.js" in systemjs.config.js file:

[image]

Comment: please remove the `angularjs` tag as this is an `angular2` question, thanks!

Comment: did u declare in the dependencies of the package json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify this line in your systemjs

```
 'lodash':                    'npm:lodash/lodash/core.js'
```

Alternatively you can use lodash cdn which makes work much easy

Comment: Thanks I will try that tomorrow and let you know

Comment: could you help me with this one as well (its to do with moduleids in components when doing an aot build): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210191/angular-2-aot-not-like-moduleid-in-my-components

Comment: Thank you @Aravind

Comment: I did the above change but it didnt work. I've attacked the git error I have above

Comment: I've added a bounty now because I'm still having trouble with this. Could you take a look?

Comment: I'm trying to get third party library's working in an aot build

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue awhile ago with some libraries i was importing so in sort a desperate attempt i removed the onWarn function:

onwarn: function(warning) {

```
// Skip certain warnings
// should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
if ( warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED' ) { return; }
// intercepts in some rollup versions
if ( warning.indexOf("The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined'") > -1 ) { return; }
// console.warn everything else
console.warn( warning.message );
```

},
from the rollup-config file and the app AOT compiled with no errors and is currently in production working just fine, now i know thats not a recommended approach for various reasons but no harm no foul i guess let me know if this helps. i can always implement something local and play around with if your still stuck.